# invalid operands to binary and external input

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a starter on C. I have this code. I have a problem scanning my input from an external.txt file.
Written this way:

```
30.5(tab)20.5(\n or newline)    
22.5(tab)3.65(\n or newline)
./prog.out < external.txt in compiling
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define LEN 2
int main()
{
    float array[2][2];
    int i;  
    int j;
    float sum;

    printf("Input 2X2 array:");
    for (i=0; i<LEN; i++){ 
        for (j=0; j<LEN; i++){ 
            scanf("%f ", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
//average of row
    for( i=0; i<LEN; i++){
        printf("row index %d:\t%f\n", i, array[i]);
        sum = sum + array[i];
        printf( "Average: %f\n", (float)sum / LEN );
    }

    return 0;
```

And I have this errors;

warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat]

:19:13: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’) in sum=sum+array[i]

Comment: For both issues, `array[i]` is an array of `float`s, not a `float`. You want `array[i][something]`.

Comment: In your `printf`, `array[i]` is a pointer not a number!

Comment: Ha ha. We posted together Paul.

Comment: You have array as 2x2, but you are only indexing one dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   scanf("%f ", &array[i][j]);
```

The format %f is not intended to catch "floats". It's for "double"s.
You need that array[i][j] be an object of type "double".
You can do one of two things:

- Change the type of your array to `double a[2][2]`.
- Or, to declare a temporal double variable to use in the `scanf()` sentence, and then assign the obtained value to `a[i][j]`.

Code:

```
printf("Input 2X2 array:");
double temp;
for (i=0; i<LEN; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j<LEN; i++){ 
        scanf("%f ", &temp);
        a[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

In the second part of your program, you have the logic wrong, because you have to obtain the average of each row. You cannot sum over rows, as in mathematics. In C you have to do the sum manually, for each row. Thus, you need iterate again on the subindexes op the array.

Anyway, I believe that you have to think again the logic of the problem.
It's not only a problem of C syntax.

Comment: instead of a[i][j], I'll call temp when I will print the array?

Comment: @user3224838: In such a case, you would need to do a previous assignment: `temp = a[i][j]`. But, since `printf()` does not need to use the memory address of `a[i][j]`, it's enough doing a cast to `double`: `printf("%f", (double) a[i][j]);`